# How to remove the units in matrix?

Tags: units

```
data={{"0.00mA", "0.18V", "43.1mV"}, {"0.02mA", "0.22V", "55.9mV"}, {"0.03mA", "0.30V", "59.4mV"}, {"0.05mA", "0.33V", "63.6mV"}, {"0.05mA", "0.36V", "79.8mV"}, {"0.07mA", "0.42V", "91.5mV"}, {"0.10mA", "0.54V", "92.6mV"}, {"0.09mA", "0.60V", "91.9mV"}, {"0.00mA", "0.15V", "39.1mV"}, {"0.00mA", "0.18V", "43.1mV"}, {"0.02mA", "0.22V", "55.9mV"}, {"0.03mA", "0.30V", "59.4mV"}, {"0.05mA", "0.33V", "63.6mV"}, {"0.05mA", "0.36V", "79.8mV"}, {"0.07mA", "0.42V", "91.5mV"}, {"0.10mA", "0.54V", "92.6mV"}, {"0.09mA", "0.60V", "91.9mV"}}
```

I use the following code,but very slow.

```
Map[QuantityMagnitude@
ReleaseHold@WolframAlpha[#, {{"Input", 1}, "Input"}] &, data, {2}]
```

How to convert it to a matrix that only contains number?

Comment: Is `QuantityMagnitude[Map[Interpreter["Quantity"], matrix, {2}]]` still too slow for your needs?

Comment: Good,I intend to use `Interpreter["Units"]`, but found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map[First@StringCases[#, NumberString] &, data, {2}]
```

This code can cater my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

**Example:**

```
MatrixForm @ Partition[StringDelete[Flatten @ data, LetterCharacter], 3]
```

*Ex. time*: `.00010723`

**Output**

[image: output example]